# Filtrar palavra em um texto com php

Tags: php

Gostaria de extrair algumas palavras em um texto com php. Mas não são palavras fixas.. Quero palavras que sempre irão mudar mas elas estarão ao lado de palavras chave padrão EX:

ID : 123123
Nome : Elvis
Endereço : Totis bla

Eu quero filtrar os valores de "ID" "Nome" "Endereço".
Não há um separador padrão ID:123, Nome: Elvis, Endereço! Ele separa por espaço, por traço, e ai vai... Porque o texto vem de um texto extraído de um arquivo PDF e salvo em uma variável ID: 123, Nome: Elvis - Endereço: toest.

Comment: Pergunta: Daonde vem estes dados? Algum Json?

Comment: @MarceloAymone isso realmente importa?? Essas informações no final onde eu vou fazer o filtro vai estar em uma variável.

Comment: Importa, porque se elas vierem de um formato json, ou algo assim, talvez seja mais simples de transformar em um array.

Comment: então, ele vem de um texto cara. Eu faço a leitura de um arquivo pdf padrão, e nesse arquivo pdf tem essas informações especificas que eu necessito retirar...

Comment: Entendi, então há a necessidade de trabalhar com a string mesmo

Comment: O valor de cada item pode ter espaço? Por exemplo, "Nome" pode vir com "Elvis da Silva"?

Comment: Ele me volta isso, onde eu salvo numa variável. Então eu queria pegar essas informações, tipo Advogado.. Código publicação..publicação....
Advogado
 
ADVOGADO (OAB: 0000 SC)
 
Código da Publicação
 
309437294
 
Disponibilização do Jornal
 
02/04/2014
 
Publicação do Jornal
 
03/04/2014

Comment: Pelo visto sim, to apanhando ai.. rsr

Comment: @MarceloAymone desculpa, é sim.. Vai ser string :D

Comment: Pelo menos tem uma ordem tipo: começa do ID, depois é o Nome e depois é o Endereço? e são separados por `:` ?

Comment: Isso, sempre serão os índices padrões com o mesmo nome, e são separados por espaço, porque vem de uma tabela.. Ai são separados por espaço

Comment: @DouglasBernardino, estava olhando aqui novamente, e pensando em outra solução para lhe ajudar, mas para isto precisaria de um exemplo mais completo, com os índices reais, teria como?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tenta assim:

```
$string = "ID : 123123 Nome : Elvis Costelo da silva Endereço : Totis bla florianópolis";

$id = preg_split('#(?<!\\\)ID :|Nome :|Endereço :#', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

$id = array_map('trim', $id); //Adicionado para eliminar os espaços

var_dump($id);
```

Imprime:

```
array (size=3)
   0 => string '123123' (length=6)
   1 => string 'Elvis Costelo da silva' (length=22)
   2 => string 'Totis bla florianópolis' (length=24)
```

**Update - Solução sem regex:** (Com Novas informações do usuário).

```
$string = "Advogado ADVOGADO (OAB: 0000 SC) Código da Publicação 309437294 Disponibilização do Jornal 02/04/2014 Publicação do Jornal 03/04/2014";

$indice = array("Advogado", "Código da Publicação", "Disponibilização do Jornal", "Publicação do Jornal");

for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($indice); $i++) {
    $a = strpos($string, $indice[$i]);
    $a_size = strlen($indice[$i]);
    if (isset($indice[$i + 1])) {
        $b = strpos($string, $indice[$i + 1]);
    } else {
        $b = strlen($string);
    }
    $valores[] = substr($string, $a + $a_size, $b - $a - $a_size);
}
$resultado = array_combine($indice, $valores);
$resultado = array_map('trim', $resultado);
var_dump($resultado);
```

Resultado:

```
array (size=4)
    'Advogado' => string 'ADVOGADO (OAB: 0000 SC)' (length=23)
    'Código da Publicação' => string '309437294' (length=9)
    'Disponibilização do Jornal' => string '02/04/2014' (length=10)
    'Publicação do Jornal' => string '03/04/2014' (length=10)
```

Comment: Se adicionar sobrenomes, complemente de endereço, funcionou aqui.

Comment: Pois é, terei que da uma verificada em expressão regular, porque essas informações eram para exemplo. Agora tenho que fazer expressão para minha necessidade.. Já ja eu testo e falo o resultado

Comment: Uhu, dá uma olhada nestas funções que utilizei, todas tem exemplos no manual do php;

Comment: Ótima solução. Pra ficar ainda melhor bastaria apenas um `array_map( 'trim', $id );`sobre **$id** pra limpar os espaços ao redor. Maiores informações sobre a ER em si, deixo como referência a quem interessar o [metacaractere modernoso](http://aurelio.net/regex/guia/modernosos.html#3_5) [(?<!ER)](http://aurelio.net/regex/guia/modernosos-nao-atras.html#3_5_6)

Comment: Verdade, vou complementar

Comment: Não conhecia essa expressão e nem tinha o costume de usar o preg_split. Muito boa a solução.

Comment: @MarceloAymone Muito bom! E muito obrigado pela atenção!

Comment: @MarceloAymone: Esse meu comentário não lhe interessa para este tópico, mas peço que quando possível dê uma olhada [nesse tópico](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1903/revers%C3%A3o-de-exclus%C3%A3o) do META que pode ser de seu interesse. Aos que acharem que isso pode ser um SPAM, essa atitude foi sugerida no próprio META por outros de maior calibre que eu.

Answer (score 2):

Não sei bem como você pega esses valores pois não está claro a questão, mas vamos dizer que seja da seguinte forma (com o separador ",").

```
$dados = "ID : 123123, Nome : Elvis, Endereço : Totis";
```

Então basta fazer o seguinte para obter as keys.

```
$dados = "ID : 123123, Nome : Elvis, Endereço : Totis";

$dadosArray = explode(',', $dados);

$dadosCorretos = array();
foreach ($dadosArray as $da) {
    $temp = explode(':', $da);
    $dadosCorretos[$temp[0]] = $temp[1];
}

$dadosKeys = array_keys($dadosCorretos);
```

O retorno será:

`dadosCorretos`:

```
array(3) {
  ["ID "]=>
  string(7) " 123123"
  [" Nome "]=>
  string(6) " Elvis"
  [" EndereÃ§o "]=>
  string(6) " Totis"
}
```

`dadosKeys`:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "ID "
  [1]=>
  string(6) " Nome "
  [2]=>
  string(11) " Endereço "
}
```

Comment: No comentário da questão está como pego esses valores... E não tem um separador padrão. Tipo, ID: 123431 - Endereço : Tide Numero: 123144, Nome: Doug

Comment: Nesse caso então tem que ser uma regex mais bem trabalhada, vou testar aqui.

Answer (score 1):

Nesse caso você pode utilizar expressões regulares (função: ereg_match ou preg_match).

Pra pegar o valor de ID, por exemplo, você pode utilizar:

```
$ereg_pattern = '/ID : (\d*)/';
$string = "ID : 123123 Nome : Elvis Endereço : Totis bla";
preg_match($ereg_pattern, $string, $matches);
```

Você terá o código ID no array $matches:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'ID : 123123' (length=11)
  1 => string '123123' (length=6)
```

Para os outros casos bastaria apenas alterar o $ereg_pattern.

Comment: cara, não entendi muito bem sua função, teria como dar uma exlpicada??

Comment: E os valores de Nome? Endereço?

Comment: Expressões regulares é um tema extenso. Em resumo: É um método de pesquisa de texto baseado em "metacaracteres". No caso, os "metacaracteres" da pesquisa está entre as / / em $ereg_pattern.
Lendo a expressão, diz-se q tem de começar com 'ID : (\d*)' significa qualquer quantidade de dígitos (o \d representa dígitos).

Então, ao rodar a função da expressão regular, ele vai procurar por esse padrão: ID : (DIGITOS), e vai jogar dentro de um array o que ele encontrou.

Eu recomendo que leia o guia do Aurélio: http://aurelio.net/regex/guia e até compre o livro, pois vale a pena. Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Beleza, entendi. Mas como eu vou fazer uma leitura num texto onde no meio do texto ele vai obter essas informações ?

Comment: Se o padrão sempre for o mesmo como você citou, a própria expressão regular vai fazer o trabalho pra você. No meu exemplo, a variável $string vai conter o seu texto.

Mas parece que o Marcelo, que entende bem de expressão regular já deu um exemplo mais completo. ;)