# Buscar por nomes dentro de um texto

Tags: php, regex, algoritmo-de-busca

Tenho um texto onde preciso buscar por nomes. O texto não tem nenhum padrão. A lista de nomes é um array. Até o momento tenho conseguido fazer normalmente, mas me deparei com uma situação onde determinado nome teve uma variante e o mesmo não foi encontrado - pois estou fazendo uma busca literal. Exemplo:

```
$nomes = array("João da Silva","Antônio de Souza Santos","Mário Faria de Oliveira");
```

Como falei, minha busca está funcionando. Mas se houver um caso em que o nome de "Antônio de Souza Santos" aparecer no texto como "Antônio de Souza" ou "Antônio Santos", não consigo encontrar.

Tentei aplicar esta solução: [Filtrar palavra em um texto com php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23511/filtrar-palavra-em-um-texto-com-php), mas não obtive muito sucesso. Alguém tem sugestão para resolver isso?

Um exemplo do texto que preciso fazer a busca:

> Data de Publicação..: 02/07/2015 1ª VARA CÍVEL Expediente de 30/06/2015 JUIZ(A) TITULAR: Nelson Marques da Silva JUIZ(A) SUBSTITUTO(A): Adriani Freire Diniz Garcia Denise Lucio Tavela Paulo Cássio Moreira JUIZ(A) PLANTONISTA: Flávio Branquinho da Costa Dias João Batista Mendes Filho Marcos Irany Rodrigues da Conceição ESCRIVÃO(Ã) : Alan Menezes Sidney PROCEDIMENTO ORDINÁRIO 00119 - 0055452.27.2011.8.13.0016 Autor: Carlos Roberto Bertholucci; Réu: Banco Bradesco Financiamentos S.A. => Vista ao réu. Prazo de 0015 dia(s) . Fica a parte ré intimada para o recolhimento da importância de R$ 290,03, a título de custas, de Taxa Judiciária, de multa penal e de outras despesas processuais devidas ao Estado, no prazo de 15 (quinze) dias, sob pena de inscrição do débito, acrescida de multa de 10% (dez por cento), em dívida ativa e de registro no Cadastro Informativo de Inadimplência em relação à Administração Pública do Estado de Minas Gerais CADIN-MG e do protesto extrajudicial da Certidão de Dívida Ativa, pela Advocacia-Geral do Estado AGE. Adv - Clovis Roberto Czegelski, Graciela Camargo Teixeira Rios, Matheus Siqueira de Alvarenga, Marta Aparecida de Castro Martiniano, Carlos Roberto de Carvalho Junior, Luciana Pereira, Francine Lopes Carvalho, Sebiana Vitale Cruz, Thaisse Christiane Schreier, Guilherme Octavio Santos Rodrigues, Marina Guimaraes Ribeiro, Fabiano Toledo Reis Souza, Leonardo Alves Bechara.

**Observação:** estou usando PHP.

Comment: Você não está usando um banco de dados? Se estiver, é mais simples fazer essa busca direto no banco.

Comment: Não. Este texto vem de um arquivo.

Comment: Quando alguém procurar por *Antônio de Souza Santos* você quer encontrar também *Antônio de Souza*, ou seria o oposto?

Comment: Pode ser os dois casos. O nome vem do banco de dados. No texto ele deve procurar as possíveis variações.

Comment: Vou explicar, se precisar, desenho: o "texto" vem de um arquivo. Os nomes vêm do banco de dados. Preciso buscar os nomes (que vem do banco de dados) no texto (que vem do arquivo). Espero que tenha ficado claro. Se precisar, explico melhor.

Comment: Acho que poderia usar `strpos` para encontrar o primeiro nome *(Antônio)*, caso encontre, procura as combinações *(Souza ou Silva)*. Não sei se *ER* serviria para esse caso.

Comment: Já tentei tanto strpos quanto ER. E não deu certo. Ou não me atende, ou eu fiz errado. Você teria uma sugestão mais prática desses dois?

Comment: @DaniloMiguel, pronto, veja se é o que postei.

Comment: @FelipeDouradinho aparentemente é isso mesmo que preciso. Vou fazer um teste junto ao meu sistema e retorno com o resultado.

Comment: @DaniloMiguel, tudo bem! Se for a resposta ideal, por favor marque-a!

Comment: @FelipeDouradinho teu script tá excelente! Só não estou conseguindo adaptar para minha realidade. Na verdade, o texto que informei ocorre diversas vezes (faço um loop no conteúdo do arquivo de origem) e em cada laço eu faço a busca dos nomes. Até encontrei uma solução, mas não deu muito certo porque pode haver repetição de nomes no mesmo texto. O problema, no caso, não é sei script, mas sim minha necessidade. Vou estudar melhor o caso e verificar qual a melhor solução.

Comment: Mas você precisa fazer a busca à cada `loop`? Por que não concatena numa string final e faz a pesquisa?

Comment: @FelipeDouradinho [continuando] Até porque, depois de localizar o nome, preciso guardar este texto (em que ocorre o nome) para enviar para um relatório depois de percorrer todo o conteúdo. De toda forma, repito, seu script é muito válido. Vou marcar sua resposta pela eficiência do conteúdo. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz uma função que percorre a lista de nomes e dá um `preg_match` no nome, onde `$nome` tem seus espaços substituídos pelo `pattern (.*?)`.

**`procura_nome.php`**

```
<?php

    /**
     * Pesquisa por nomes em um texto, recebendo $nomes como array
     *
     * @param   array   $nomes
     * @param   string  $texto
     * @return  array
     */
    function pesquisaNomes($nomes, $texto)
    {

        $todos_resultados = [];

        if(is_array($nomes) && !empty($nomes))
        {
            foreach ($nomes as $key => $nome)
            {
                $resultado = [];
                preg_match("/".str_replace(" ", '(.*?)', $nome)."/i", $texto, $resultado);
                $resultado = array_filter(array_map('trim', $resultado));

                if(!empty($resultado))
                {
                    $todos_resultados[$nome] = $resultado[0];
                }
            }

        }
        return $todos_resultados;
    }


    $nomes = array (
        'João da Silva',
        'Antônio de Souza Santos',
        'Antônio de Souza',
        'Antônio Santos',
        'Mário Faria de Oliveira',
        'Nelson Marques',
        'Nelson da Silva',
    );

    $texto = 'Data de Publicação..: 02/07/2015 1ª VARA CÍVEL Expediente de 30/06/2015. Procurar por Antônio de Souza Santos. JUIZ(A) TITULAR: Nelson Marques da Silva JUIZ(A) SUBSTITUTO(A): Adriani Freire Diniz Garcia Denise Lucio Tavela Paulo Cássio Moreira JUIZ(A) PLANTONISTA: Flávio Branquinho da Costa Dias João Batista Mendes Filho Marcos Irany Rodrigues da Conceição ESCRIVÃO(Ã) : Alan Menezes Sidney PROCEDIMENTO ORDINÁRIO 00119 - 0055452.27.2011.8.13.0016 Autor: Carlos Roberto Bertholucci; Réu: Banco Bradesco Financiamentos S.A. => Vista ao réu. Prazo de 0015 dia(s) . Fica a parte ré intimada para o recolhimento da importância de R$ 290,03, a título de custas, de Taxa Judiciária, de multa penal e de outras despesas processuais devidas ao Estado, no prazo de 15 (quinze) dias, sob pena de inscrição do débito, acrescida de multa de 10% (dez por cento), em dívida ativa e de registro no Cadastro Informativo de Inadimplência em relação à Administração Pública do Estado de Minas Gerais CADIN-MG e do protesto extrajudicial da Certidão de Dívida Ativa, pela Advocacia-Geral do Estado AGE. Adv - Clovis Roberto Czegelski, Graciela Camargo Teixeira Rios, Matheus Siqueira de Alvarenga, Marta Aparecida de Castro Martiniano, Carlos Roberto de Carvalho Junior, Luciana Pereira, Francine Lopes Carvalho, Sebiana Vitale Cruz, Thaisse Christiane Schreier, Guilherme Octavio Santos Rodrigues, Marina Guimaraes Ribeiro, Fabiano Toledo Reis Souza, Leonardo Alves Bechara';

    var_export(pesquisaNomes($nomes, $texto));
```

**Resultado**

```
array (
  'Antônio de Souza Santos' => 'Antônio de Souza Santos',
  'Antônio de Souza' => 'Antônio de Souza',
  'Antônio Santos' => 'Antônio de Souza Santos',
  'Nelson Marques' => 'Nelson Marques',
  'Nelson da Silva' => 'Nelson Marques da Silva',
)
```

Comment: A ideia é interessante mas tem problemas: "Carlos Pereira", encontraria "Carlos Roberto de Carvalho Junior, Luciana Pereira". Propunha pelo menos excuil contuação e afins: `'([^.,;!]*?)'`